# Creating a universal function of email image handling across multiple clients

Tags: php, regex, html-email

I have a set of scripts that manages an email account and posts them to a MySQL table. Most email clients handle images inserted into the bodies as **cid:** and browser cannot view these links.

So i have a set of code that i tested with Outlook 2010, that will extract the images from the email and save them to a directory. The issue i am having is that emails will be sent using various email clients, and so far i've only successfully handle Outlook 2010's images. How can i create a set of functions to manage them successfully? As sort of a universal image function:
A block of my code:

```
/***************************** 1st image in email**********************************/
if (preg_match('/cid:([^"@]*).(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp)@([^"]*)/', $html_part, $m)){

$find = '/cid:'.$m[1].'.'.$m[2].'@([^"]*)/';

if ($m[2] == 'png') $replace = $png1;
if ($m[2] == 'jpg') $replace = $jpg1;
if ($m[2] == 'gif') $replace = $gif1;
if ($m[2] == 'bmp') $replace = $bmp1;
if ($m[2] == 'jpeg') $replace = $jpeg1;
$html_part = preg_replace($find, $replace, $html_part);
}

/***************************** 2nd image in email**********************************/                        
if (preg_match('/cid:([^"@]*).(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp)@([^"]*)/', $html_part, $m)){

$find = '/cid:'.$m[1].'.'.$m[2].'@([^"]*)/';

if ($m[2] == 'png') $replace = $png2;
if ($m[2] == 'jpg') $replace = $jpg2;
if ($m[2] == 'gif') $replace = $gif2;
if ($m[2] == 'bmp') $replace = $bmp2;
if ($m[2] == 'jpeg') $replace = $jpeg2;

$html_part = preg_replace($find, $replace, $html_part);
}
```

But when it comes down to other email clients i've tested:
Windows Live Mail:

```
src=3D"cid:813DEC0642E941F0845447B680DA566A@BrinardHP"
```

Hotmail:

```
src="https://*****.storage.live.com/y1pZinLnQnaoBClW=RMsQ5sAzEF1H4HGond-KoaAjdcEX0GCp9HzrWa2RSJwI9ngxR7WIub5M9Ps810/cloudsprite.=jpg"
```

iPhone's default mail app

```
src="cid:1D8E2297-F260-4555-8223-304A9DB08CC5/image.jpeg"
```

So instead of spending days possibly coding an image handler based on a specific email clients cid: references, how can i say, loop through all the images in the directory that has just been saved and apply them correctly to their positions in the email body.
So the $replace links are hyperlink references to the image that has been saved to the directory. Thanks.

Comment: I like your idea of starting a catalog of CID format examples attached to this message, you might add some more.  With regards to your final question, have you verified that the saved images will retain unique enough filenames to match the email body?

Comment: Well an internal script i have saves all attachments from the emails to a pre-defined directory, that should verify it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Not saying you shouldn't but there might be a better way of achieving whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: This was several months ago, i've moved past this and found a solution.

Comment: @Tower Then why don't you share the solution with us in the answers section ?

Comment: Sure @HamZa I went with an email class solution found here: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-email-message-class-extracting-attachments and integrated it with the rest of my script where necessary.

Comment: @Tower could you post it as an answer below, and then accept it - otherwise it comes up as 'unanswered'. If you're feeling lazy, you could just close the question.